# Delphi - Install , Start ,Stop Service inside application with Form

Tags: delphi

i have Delphi application and i added **service** to it , how can i install and start and stop it by **Main Form** buttons ?

i can do it in separate project service , but my goal is make interface for service to control it .

Thanks

Comment: I would have voted to close as a duplicate, but this is two questions in one (Install Service, and Start/Stop Service), each of which can be found by a simple search. No votes, just this could be answered without asking a question.

Comment: Please clarify what you really mean in your question to avoid confusion as found in comments on the answers below.

Comment: I'm understanding this question as "How do I install, start, and stop a Windows Service Application from within my Forms Application?"

Comment: yes ,i mean as your in last comment,  Start,Stop service  from application Form which my service hosted in same application(part of my application).

sorry for my bad English .
you can see this picture to understand me .
http://www.nowsms.com/discus/messages/1/70354.png

Comment: As Remy and I both said, you can't do this **from the same application** as your service any more, since Windows Vista.

Comment: Now I have a good vision on the subject.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have a visual interface to your service in the same application any longer.

As of Windows Vista and above, services run in a different desktop than the user and can't visually interact with the user. You need to write a separate application that communicates with your service via named pipes, mailslots, or some other form of interprocess communication, or through one of the [`service control functions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685942%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) available through the Windows API.

Comment: I don't believe that's what's being asked, OP is asking how to install and start/stop a service from another application.

Comment: @JerryDodge Second paragraph tells about a service with an included control interface, and that is impossible.

Comment: That second paragraph doesn't make much sense to me, it's overly broad, which is why I voted to close. "make interface for service to control it" could mean many things.

Comment: Plus how do you expect to start the service from the service?

Comment: @Jerry, read the *first paragraph* of the question. It's pretty clear:"i have Delphi application and i added service to it". "I have application" and "I added service to it"? And I never said anything about "starting the service from a service". I said "write a separate application that communicates with your service ... or uses one of the service control functions available in the API". Did you look at the link I posted at all? Remy mentioned the same specific functions I did. :-)

Comment: I wasn't commenting on the words in your answer in relation to "start a service from a service". I mean, if the OP wants to start/stop a service from the service, how do they expect to do so?

Comment: @Jerry: Oh, Ok. I would have thought that would be in a comment to the question, so I misunderstood. :-) Sorry.

Comment: Thanks Ken You understand what I mean very well, and now I understand what I have to do.

Comment: "You can't have a visual interface to your service in the same application any longer."... But you can... it just takes some work and fiddling. If you don't want to do it yourself, use [svcom](http://www.aldyn-software.com/svcom.html) Luke :-)

Comment: @MarjanVenema - any references on quality of the svcom components? I'm shopping around because I don't want to deal with services low-level code for now, and need to provide this functionality real soon.

Comment: @Marjan: According to MS, you're not supposed to (see [Service Changes for Windows Vista](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb203962%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), particularly "Session 0 Isolation"). SVCom is a workaround that shouldn't be used, IMO. You should be following the guidelines established by the OS, and there's no guarantee that things won't change further in the future.

Comment: @KenWhite: Sorry, of course, when the app is started as a service, it shouldn't show any forms whatsoever. Very inconvenient though for debugging. So all our service applications can start in "debug" mode (given a -debug command line parameter) and then do show a debug form and start as a forms application. Without it, they show nothing and start as a service application.

Comment: @Marjan I do that too, every service I build is around a common shell, where the app can be launched as a dummy service (forms app) with a start/stop button and a log view.

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera: They served us well for years. The only reason we stopped using them is that the service wrapper was the only part of the svcom library we used and thus svcom  was an easy target in a drive to reduce the number of third party dependencies when we switched to Unicode.

Comment: @Marjan: You're talking about an app that can run as either a service or an application (either/or). That doesn't appear to be what the user is asking for here, though. The question is about creating a service that has a GUI that can control it ("my goal is make interface for service to control it"), which is what my answer was about (and to which you're commenting). :-)

Comment: True, it's just that I have found developing any service application _without_ this ability is a royal pain in the behind when it comes to debugging and that is what I wanted to point out. Somewhat too terse and skipping a few steps of my thought process, in the first, I'll admit :-)

Answer (score 9):

You have to use the Win32 API Service Control functions - `CreateService()`, `OpenService()`,  `StartService()`, `ControlService()`, etc.  A service cannot display its own UI while it is running, the UI needs to be run as a separate process.  But you can host the Service code and UI code in the same executable if you want to, using command-line parameters to know when to run as a service and when to run as a UI.  But that is more of a code management issue. You could just as easily host the two codebases in separate executables instead.